# HTML Buttons wont stop wrapping

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have some HTML/CSS buttons near the top of my webpage lined up next to each other horizontally.  Everything works fine when the webpage is viewed as normal(fullscreen) but when you resize the browser window(i.e.  making it not fullscreen) the buttons start to disappear.  Each button disappears individually as you start to drag the width-extent of the browser-window over the button.  In case I'm not explaining this very well, here our pictures demonstrating it.

Before dragging over button:

[image: Before dragging over button]

After dragging over button:

[image: After dragging over button]

I have tried the common fix for similar questions on stack overflow by including "float: left" and "white-space: nowrap" in the CSS class but the buttons still wrap. 
The HTML for making the buttons is:

```
  <div class="buttons">
    <div onmousedown="return false"><a class="aBtn" href="DPS_Guitarspg3.html">Guitars</a></div>
    <div onmousedown="return false"><a class="aBtn" href="DPS_Guitarspg4.html">Basses</a></div>
    <div onmousedown="return false"><a class="aBtn" href="DPS_Guitarspg2.html">Our Philosophy</a></div>
    <div onmousedown="return false"><a class="aBtn" href="DPS_Guitarspg5.html">Custom Orders</a></div>
    <div onmousedown="return false"><a class="aBtn" href="DPS_Guitarspg6.html">Contact Us</a></div>
  </div>
```

The CSS for the 'aBtn' class is:

```
.aBtn {
  /*left-10 due to automated spaceing in browser*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color:rgb(111,0,100);
  background-color:rgb(0,0,5);
  border:1px solid transparent;
  font-family: "arial";
  padding:8px 40px;
  width: auto;
  height: 5%;
  top:60px;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what is your goal, but you can add fixed width to button container....

Comment: i based on @nevermind say use the fix width than the button wont go down is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/ych87nz1/

Comment: what do you want to happen when the window/container becomes so narrow that they don't fit in there anymore - get smaller, have a scrollbar, be placed vertically, be hidden?

Comment: I want them to become  hidden  from view after the window narrows

Answer (score 0):

use either `width`or `min-width` in the button class and set `display` to either block or inline-block

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what your goal is for this, but you could try to `float` the buttons `right` rather than `left` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: the goal is to have the buttons stay where they are when the window edge crosses over them. So the button eventually should not appear anymore even though it is technically  just outside of the viewable screen